# A python text io stream with peek?

Tags: python

BufferedReader is great, but it isn't a text io stream and I don't want to decode UTF-8 on my own. For that I should use TextIOWrapper, but that doesn't have a peek method. In some cases I guess I could implement `peek(n): result = read(n); seek(-len(result), SEEK_CUR)`, but without writing my own buffer or my own UTF-8 decoding, what should I do?